# Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: root

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am getting started with mysql database for my NODEJS application
const mysql = require('mysql2');

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  root: 'root',
  database:'node-complete',
  password: 'Pratik@123'
})
```

My root password is the one coded above.

I am getting this error:-

> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: root.
> This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection

Can some help me to fix this issue?

```
module.exports = pool.promise()
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem, i used

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    username: 'root',
    database: 'node-complete',
    password: '24GM@L@PM+AU',
    port: '3306'
});
```

its not supposed to say "username" but instead just "user" like below

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node-complete',
    password: '24GM@L@PM+AU',
    port: '3306'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

it works when you change `username` to `user`:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    
    host: 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    database : 'node-complete',
    password : 'node-complete'

});
```

PS: I watch the same lecture as you do `(  database : 'node-complete', )` gave it away  :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

the property in connection options must be named **user**, not **root**

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database:'node-complete',
  password: 'Pratik@123'
});
```

Comment: My property in connection was named `user` but I also still got the error message, just like the OP.

What can be the issue? @slkorolev

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the  connection property **root** as **user**

const pool = mysql.createPool({
host:'localhost',
user:'root',
password:'admin',
database:'node-complete'
})

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed "username" to "user"

```js
const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password@2023"
});
```